# Apply ListCollectionView to DataGrid without blocking UI

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to find a way to apply a `ListCollectionView` to a `DataGrid` in WPF in such a way that the UI remains responsive while the view is updated.

The `DataGrid` displays a large set of data, which must be grouped. Currently, I'm using a `ListCollectionView` to do this, but when applying the `ListCollectionView`, the UI locks up which I believe is the result of having to load the entire data set thus preventing virtualisation.

I do not need to reduce the loading time as this routine is used for reporting and will not be run frequently, however I do need to prevent the UI from locking up while the `ListCollectionView` is applied.

I would like the `ListCollectionView` to be applied in background thread while a `BusyIndicator` displays a message over the grid.

Currently, the data in the grid is populated as shown below, where:

`DataRecord` is the name of the relevant table, and also the name of the EF object which represents a row from that table.

`IsBusy` is a bool which is bound to the `IsBusy` property of a `BusyIndicator` from the extended WPF toolkit which wraps the `DataGrid` in the view.

`RecordsList` is a `List<DataRecord>` object which is bound to the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid`.

NB. The code shown below has been altered to make it more generic. This snippet is taken from a live project and has been changed to hide client data and identity.

```
 private void DisplayAllRecords() {
        IsBusy = true;
        String sqlConnect = SqlConnectionString;
        DbConnection connection = EFConnectionFactory.MakeConnection(sqlConnect);
        List<DataRecord> Batches = new List<DataRecord>();

        using (var db = new efContext(connection)) {

            DbSet<DataRecord> Result = db.DataRecords;

            foreach (DataRecord dr in Result) {
                RecordsList.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(RecordsList);
        lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("authorisedBy"));

        DataRecordsGridContent = lcv;
        IsBusy = false;
    }
```

The routine runs in the `ViewModel`, and the relationship between `View` and `ViewModel` is created as View First using a `DataTemplate` defined in `App.xaml` as follows.

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DataRecordViewModel}">
     <Views:DataRecordView />
 </DataTemplate>
```

In this form, the `DataGrid` is populated as it should be, however with the `ListCollectionView` enabled, the process takes in excess of 30 seconds to populate the grid as there are a vast number of rows, thus it cannot be lazy loaded.

I have tried to place the entire routine in a `BackgroundWorker`, in a `Task`, and running it on the `Dispatcher`, to no avail. The UI is blocked until the `ListCollectionView` has been applied.

I have had no luck either by placing the assignment of the `ListCollectionView` in a background task (using the same approaches as with the entire routine). In this case, the UI did not display at all until the `ListCollectionView` was rendered.

Setting `IsBusy` correctly shows the loading message over the `DataGrid` when no data is populated.

The desired result is that the UI will load, the window will be rendered, and the `BusyIndicator` will be shown until the `ListCollectionView` is applied to the `DataGrid`. Once this is complete, the `BusyIndicator` will be hidden.

Can anybody advise if this is possible without having to implement my own grouping method?
It seems counter intuitive that I should need to change the grouping method just to stop the `ListCollectionView` being loaded on the UI thread thus locking up the UI completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect to and query the database on a background thread but create the `ListCollectionView` back on the UI thread:

```
private void DisplayAllRecords()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //this code is executed on a background thread
        String sqlConnect = SqlConnectionString;
        DbConnection connection = EFConnectionFactory.MakeConnection(sqlConnect);
        List<DataRecord> Batches = new List<DataRecord>();

        using (var db = new efContext(connection))
        {
            DbSet<DataRecord> Result = db.DataRecords;

            foreach (DataRecord dr in Result)
            {
                RecordsList.Add(dr);
            }
        }
    }).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        //this code is executed back on the UI thread
        ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(RecordsList);
        DataRecordsGridContent = lcv;
        IsBusy = false;
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

If the actual rendering of the UI elements is slow, as opposed to the retrieval of the data, you should make sure that you haven't somehow disabled the UI virtualization in your view.

Also note that grouping a fairly large `CollectionView` using a `PropertyGroupDescription` is convenient and very flexible but slow. You may want to consider grouping the collection by yourself, for example using LINQ, and then customize the look of your "group" rows in the view.

Comment: I had made a mistake when posting my code sample. The sample as shown previously loads very quickly, however I had ommitted the line where I apply a `PropertyGroupDescription` to the collection. Is is applying the group description which seems to be time consuming, however it may be that the entire data set has to be retrieved before the grouping can be applied whereas previously only the visible portion of the data is loaded and rendered while the remaining loading takes place in the background.

Comment: Group the data by yourself then instead of using a PropertyGroupDescription.

Comment: Will grouping the results during the load from the DB still allow me to use a `DataGrid.GroupStyle` in the XAML?

Comment: No: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155424/wpf-datagrid-v-fast-grouping-v-slow-how-to-display-group-rows-without-using-gr

Comment: I did look at that thread, and the linked blog entry when I was working on this issue initially. My primary concern here is not really to speed up the loading, or implement an alternative grouping, just to place the loading and rendering of data in a background thread in some way so that the UI doesn't freeze. I gather that the filtering happens on the UI thread at a pre-defined priority, so I'm looking for some way to circumvent that if it's possible.

Comment: ok, so the nature of the `ListCollectionView` is that you specify conditions to filter on, apply it to the `DataGrid`, and the conditions are not applied until the point at which it is rendered? In which case, there is absolutely no way to do this whatsoever without grouping at the point the data is loaded, thus making the `ListCollectionView` largely pointless with any large collection.

Comment: Yes, more or less.

Comment: Ok, re-factoring time then. This does seem like a huge oversight on the part of MS that you can't pre-group a data set then apply it to the UI without blocking it. I can see the reasoning behind keeping the view seperate from the underlying data, but I would have expected the filtering to provide a data set which can be rendered directly without farming out the work to the UI thread. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Grouping a ListCollectionView by adding a PropertyGroupDescription is convenient and very flexible but it isn't fast when binding to large collections.

Comment: Refectored to group the result set using Linq before applying to the bound data source on the grid. It's now working significantly quicker and the busy indicator is working. Would you mind adding a line to your answer regarding grouping the data before rendering please so I can mark it as the correct solution? Many thanks for your help.